# How to create the text editor like slack message editor

Tags: angular, editor, chat

Now, I work on angular project. I am going to create a chat app with  message editor like the message editor of slack app.
But I cannot find any resource and reference data.
If you know the resource or url, please show me.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://lexical.dev/ this is framework (and gui) independent text editor framework, so it' s ideal to use as a chat message editor bacause you have full control over the gui.